# Error openning my hard-drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, live-environment

I'm trying to open my main hard drive (on live environment - my ubuntu is on usb device) but I got the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/C0F89410F89406B6: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/C0F89410F89406B6"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Note that I have play with the partitons when trying install ubuntu (It didn't happen himself).
This error occur in Ubuntu(live) and my WIN8 that is in the hard drive con't booting becaus of this.

what can I do?

Comment: Are you using Windows 8 or better?

Comment: @Raphael I edited the question.

Comment: @souravc No. There he can boot into windows. I'm cant to. There the problem is because Windows is hibernated instead of turned off. My problem is because of things I did no responsibility. Please get the duplicate tag off.